# Save text file with multiple highlights in color

Tags: editors

I have a text file which I am reading, it is too long and sometimes I need to mark content in it for later reference.

I want to be able to highlight multiple lines in the file with color and save this file with highlights so that when I turn on my system back again and open the file for reading, the highlights are in place.

Answer (score 2):

Would adding a comment in the file with a certain string work?

For example, if the file had a comment format of  // you could add this line to the file:

//READLATER

and when you wanted to read it later you could find lines containing "//READLATER"

This is what I would do for command line.  I don't know if you are using command line or a GUI, I have almost no experience with using linux GUIs so I can't help you there

Comment: No, I am looking for colored highlight only.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Any editor goes, I use vim, gedit, nano, emacs

Comment: IMHO, I suggest you post this as comment because this isn't an answer

Comment: I don't know if that is a thing for any linux text editor as they typically just edit the files as they are.  You could possibly use syntax highlighting with a comment but otherwise,  I have no idea, sorry

Comment: I need more rep to post comments, and while it isn't an answer, it's a valid workaround imo

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut This answer is still a good idea (+1 from me).  you could rename the file to `filename.md`, edit it with `vim` (or some other editor that can do syntax highlighting for markdown) and add highlights as you like.   Markdown is plain-text with highlighting (and other fancy stuff if you view/print it in rendered rather than plain-text mode).

Answer (score 0):

The keyword to search for is *bookmark*. These are built-in for emacs (and probably many editors). You can mark any place in a file and have these positions saved, not within the file, but in a separate "repository" of all bookmarks (Try <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`bookmark`<kbd>return</kbd>).

However, if you want highlighting you might prefer to download the alternative [bm.el](https://github.com/joodland/bm) file. This provides a similar but independent function which is probably more convivial. Apart from downloading and loading the file you will need to configure some things, for example adding a binding to allow you to highlight by clicking in the emacs margin. By default the bookmarks are not persistent, so you need at least

```
(setq-default bm-buffer-persistence t)
```

A much larger alternative that is compatible with the built-in bookmarks is [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) which also provides for highlighting.